# Where Clause Rejecting Rows if NULL occurred

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, null, isnull

A Theory Question...

When a set of queries as given below is fired then...

```
Create table Temp1(C1 varchar(2))
Create table Temp2(C1 varchar(2))
insert into Temp1 Values('A'),(NULL),('B')
insert into Temp2 Values('B'),(NULL),('C'),(NULL)

select *from Temp1 A,Temp2 B
where A.C1 <> B.C1
```

...gives...

[image: Actual Result]

I used `A.C1 <> B.C1` in the `Where` clause.

---

But I expect...

[image]

To get expected result as output I needed to use `ISNULL(A.C1,'') <> ISNULL(B.C1,'')` in the `Where` clause.

My Question is why do I need to use `ISNULL` every time for getting output as expected, as `NULL` is not equal to any string data.

Comment: Because null has a special meaning of no value.  any comparisons where one side is null will yield null and evaluate to false - read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Anything compared to `NULL` always returns `NULL` (unknown) which is neither true nor false and therefore can't meet your criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from [here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/18/why-null-never-compares-false-to-anything-in-sql/) is perfect:

> The correct way to understand NULL is that it is not a value. Not
>   “this is a NULL value” but “this NULL is not a value.” Everything
>   either is a value, or it isn’t. When something is a value, it is “1,”
>   or “hello,” or “green,” or “$5.00″ etc — but when something isn’t a
>   value, it just isn’t anything at all. SQL represents “this has no
>   value” by the special non-value NULL. When someone says “the NULL
>   value,” one should mentally disagree, because there’s no such thing.
>   NULL is the complete, total absence of any value whatsoever.

Null is not equal to anything, therefore comparison always fails.

For example try this query:

```
select *
from Temp2 B
where B.C1 = null
```

it won't return any row!

The handle nulls you have to use `is null` or `is not null`:

```
select *
from Temp1 A, Temp2 B
where A.C1 <> B.C1 or (A.C1 is null and B.C1 is not null) or (B.C1 is null and A.C1 is not null)
```

return exactly the same values that your query with `ISNULL` returns.